# Non diagonally incrementing pairing function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking for a pairing function $J:\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ which does graphically seen not progress diagonally like the [Cantor pairing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJd61.png).

Instead it should always try to maintain the rough shape of a square.

```
1   2   5   10   17 . . .

3   4   7   12   19

6   8   9   14   21

11  13  15  16   23

18  20  22  24   25
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 - 2(x-y), & x\ge y\\
y^2 - 2(y-x)+1 , & x\lt y
\end{cases}
$$

Which also can be written as:

$$
f(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}^2-2|x-y|+\delta_{x\lt y}
$$

Where $\delta_{y\lt x}$ is an indicator function and is $1$ if $(x\lt y)$, and is $0$ otherwise ($x\ge y$).

Produces the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 17 & 26 & 37 & 50 & 65 & 82  & \dots \\
 3 & 4 & 7 & 12 & 19 & 28 & 39 & 52 & 67 & 84 & \dots \\
 6 & 8 & 9 & 14 & 21 & 30 & 41 & 54 & 69 & 86 & \dots \\
 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 23 & 32 & 43 & 56 & 71 & 88 & \dots \\
 18 & 20 & 22 & 24 & 25 & 34 & 45 & 58 & 73 & 90 & \dots \\
 27 & 29 & 31 & 33 & 35 & 36 & 47 & 60 & 75 & 92 & \dots \\
 38 & 40 & 42 & 44 & 46 & 48 & 49 & 62 & 77 & 94 & \dots \\
 51 & 53 & 55 & 57 & 59 & 61 & 63 & 64 & 79 & 96 & \dots \\
 66 & 68 & 70 & 72 & 74 & 76 & 78 & 80 & 81 & 98 & \dots \\
 83 & 85 & 87 & 89 & 91 & 93 & 95 & 97 & 99 & 100 & \dots \\
\dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots&
\end{array}
$$

Notice that it isn't hard to come up with such a function:

1. Observe that the terms on the main diagonal of the table are squares $n^2$.
2. When at main diagonal and moving up (decrease $y$ by $1$), terms decrease by $2$.
3. This gives you the upper half of the table (from the main diagonal and up).
4. Finally, the bottom half is just symmetric to the upper half, plus $1$.

Comment: Works perfectly.